# NodeJs - youtube.search.list returns id: [object]

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-data-api, discord.js

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const config = require(__dirname + "/../../config/settings.json");
const google = require('googleapis');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const youtube = google.youtube({
 version: 'v3',
 auth: config.gapi
});
class PlayCommand extends commando.Command {
constructor(client) {
super(client, {
  name: 'play',
  group: "music",
  memberName: 'play',
  description: 'Plays music from youtube',
});
}
async run(message, args) {
youtube.search.list({
  maxResults: '5',
  part: 'snippet',
  type: 'video',
  q: args
},
function (err, request) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error: ' + err);
  }
if (request) {
  console.log(request)
}
});
}
}
module.exports = PlayCommand
```

Here's my play command so far, the problem is whenever i type `>play args`,
I get this:

```
{ kind: 'youtube#searchListResponse',
 etag: '"S8kisgyDEblalhHF9ooXPiFFrkc/C1WPrLHrbjq3iYDhZhQ4QT0ahKc"',
 nextPageToken: 'CAUQAA',
 regionCode: 'PL',
 pageInfo: { totalResults: 1000000, resultsPerPage: 5 },
items:
  { kind: 'youtube#searchResult',
   etag: '"S8kisgyDEblalhHF9ooXPiFFrkc/HI2NmsFJ4wN7_PF5bDbDq-1kshA"',
   id: [Object],
   snippet: [Object] },
```

Only the id of the video is important for now, but as you can see it returns as `[Object]`
I really don't know what to do, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When logging the results of YouTube-Search, it will usually not show any deep objects. Due to this, the object does exist, you just need to log it in specific. For example,

```
console.log(request.items[0]);
```

This should output the entire first result, including the object found. Another good method to get results quickly is the [YouTube-Search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search) module. From my experience with the Google API, it can be quite weird sometimes and change constantly, so using modules helps out a lot with keeping up with Google's changes.